# rails relationship one-to-many; can't build child objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship, table-relationships

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :boosts, class_name: BoostedPhoto
    ...
end

class BoostedPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :photo
end
```

This is how I have it set up so far, but when i try to do this in the console:

```
photo = Photo.first
photo.boosts.create(title: 'testing')
```

I get the following results

```
(0.3ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: photo_id
```

Been looking up how to do relationships for a few hours, and I think I might be overlooking something really simple...sorry for the newb question, but I'm starting to pull my hair out from frustration!

Comment: Do you have a column named `photo_id` in the `BoostedPhoto`? This column is used by rails to save the association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a foreign key column in the `boosted_photos` table. General rule is the we put `belongs_to` association in the table model which have the foreign key, here it is `BoostedPhoto`

After that following should work,

```
photo = Photo.first
photo.boosts.create(title: 'testing')
```

Comment: Worked great for me. It seems that photo.boosts.build(title: 'testing') would also work. Thank you.